# How to oEmbed from custom field, responsive to container size and responsive

Tags: custom-field, responsive, oembed

I am using Magic Fields 2 to add custom fields/meta boxes.

One custom field is for a Vimeo or YouTube video URL to be displayed.

The following [code oEmbeds the video URL](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/oembed-and-custom-field?replies=3):

```
<?php if (!((get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_url', TRUE))=='')) {
    echo wp_oembed_get( get_post_meta($post->ID, "video_url", true) );
}?>
```

To resize the video, I have used added the code inside `<div class="video">` and resized it using CSS - `.video iframe {width:500px;height:312px}`.

The problem, this method is not responsive.

I have also tried `.video iframe {width:95%;height:95%}`. This outputs looks like -

[image]

The [Fluid Video Embeds plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/fluid-video-embeds/) seems to do the job for oEmbeds through the normal WordPress method and through shortcode, but not with using a custom field.

Comment: So you want the div to keep the aspect ratio of the embed via js/css? I'd think that's not a WordPress issue and has little to do with the WP OEmbed process other than coincidence/circumstance

Comment: If that's the case, can you migrate this to a different SE site? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this is completely relevant to WordPress. WordPress has built in oEmbed and I have included a method that allows for responsive oEmbeds using a WordPress plugin. The specific issue is how to complete task when the oEmbed is a custom field... But screw it... Close the question because mods do not know the answer... That seems to be the trend here the past 9 months or so. I have talked to a LOT of WP users... This is viewed as an unhelpful and elitist WP community lately. Sad, it used to be helpful.

Comment: Is it absolutely imperative that this be oEmbed? Seems this can be accomplished with FluidVids (resize) http://142.4.8.79/~sfmc/video/aaa-screening/ or without (resize) http://lakecookortho.com/video/peter/

Comment: I'm not a mod, I'm another user, the only difference between me and you is that I have more reputation here at the moment, who knows that may change. From my experience it looks like you have a CSS problem, namely "given an element, how do I maintain an aspect ratio of A:B while resizing?" which is a css/js question applied to the output.

Comment: Having googled, every article I've found so far uses something like fitvid.js to fix the problem. So no this is not a WordPress issue, it's a js/css issue that just happens to be on a WordPress site. You wouldn't phone up the builder of your house if your kettle broke because the kettle was located inside a house would you? Or phone your carmaker up because your wallet ripped and you just happened to be sitting in a car?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completed the task with [fitvids.js](http://fitvidsjs.com/) by using the plugin [FitVids for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/fitvids-for-wordpress/).

Chris Coyier describes the integration with WordPress in his screencast [Integrating FitVids.js into WordPress](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/103-integrating-fitvids-js-into-wordpress/) ([on YouTube](http://youtu.be/GGQwlSps_Hs)).

My custom field name is `video_url`. I used the following code in my template:

```
<?php if (!((get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_url', TRUE))=='')) {
    echo wp_oembed_get( get_post_meta($post->ID, "video_url", true) );
}?>
```

In the settings of FitVids for WordPress, simply enter the containing div class or ID which represents the maximum width of the video.

[image]

For those who need it, Integrating FitVids.js into WordPress screencast shows how to check the theme for jQuery and for the proper CSS selector.